Engulfing Candle Detection
I am trying to add a bullish and bearish engulfing candle detection into my script. I have the code to calculate it, however, I am getting an error "More than one 'title' arguments are supplied. Only the first one will be used." I am not sure how to fix it.
indicator("GoldenGate Algo v2.0", overlay=true)

// Inputs
PeriodFast = 50//input(50, title="Fast Period")
PeriodSlow = 200//input(200, title="Slow Period")
PeriodDailyFast = 8//input(8, title="Daily Fast Period")
PeriodDailySlow = 21//input(21, title="Daily Slow Period")
Len = 6//input(6, title="RSI Length")
//useEngulfing = input(false, title="Use Engulfing Patterns for Signals")

// Variables
var isLong = false
var isShort = false

// ——————————— <calculations>
bullishEngulfing = open[1] > close[1] ? close > open ? close >= open[1] ? close[1] >=         open ? close - open > open[1] - close[1] ? color.blue :na :na : na : na : na
bearishEngulfing = close[1] > open[1] ? open > close ? open >= close[1] ? open[1] >=     close ? open - close > close[1] - open[1] ? color.purple :na :na : na : na : na


// Evaluate EMAs
DailyFastEMA = ta.ema(close, PeriodDailyFast)
DailySlowEMA = ta.ema(close, PeriodDailySlow)

// EMAs and RSI calculation
emaFast = ta.ema(close, PeriodFast)
emaSlow = ta.ema(close, PeriodSlow)
plotDailyFastEMA = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', DailyFastEMA)
plotDailySlowEMA = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', DailySlowEMA)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, Len)


// Buy/Sell
buyCondition = not isLong and emaFast > emaSlow and rsi < 25 and close > open //and (not useEngulfing or bullEngulfing)
sellCondition = not isShort and emaFast < emaSlow and rsi > 75 and close < open //and (not useEngulfing or bearEngulfing)
if (buyCondition)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false
    
if (sellCondition)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

// Plot signals
// the error shows here
plotshape(bullishEngulfing != na, buyCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, text='Long', textcolor=color.gray, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title = "Long Signal")
plotshape(bullishEngulfing != na, sellCondition, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, text='Short', textcolor=color.gray, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title = "Short Signal")

// Plot EMAs
plot(emaFast, title="EMA Fast", color=color.purple, linewidth = 2)
plot(emaSlow, title="EMA Slow", color=color.orange, linewidth = 2)
plot(plotDailyFastEMA, title="Daily EMA Fast", color=#27b027, linewidth = 2, display=display.none)
plot(plotDailySlowEMA, title="Daily EMA Slow", color=#911111, linewidth = 2, display=display.none)

// Define bullish/bearish conditions for each timeframe
bullish = emaFast > emaSlow
bearish = emaFast < emaSlow
bullish_daily = plotDailyFastEMA > plotDailySlowEMA
bearish_daily = plotDailyFastEMA < plotDailySlowEMA

// Print table for daily and current trends
var table trendTable = table.new(position = position.bottom_left, columns = 4, rows = 3)
table.cell(trendTable, 1, 1, "Current Trend", bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white)
table.cell(trendTable, 1, 2, "Daily Trend", bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white)
table.cell(trendTable, 2, 1, bullish ? "Bullish" : bearish ? "Bearish" : "Neutral", bgcolor = bullish ? color.green : bearish ? color.red : color.gray, text_color = color.white)
table.cell(trendTable, 2, 2, bullish_daily ? "Bullish" : bearish_daily ? "Bearish" : "Neutral", bgcolor = bullish_daily ? color.green : bearish_daily ? color.red : color.gray, text_color = color.white)

// Pivot Points Calculation
[yHigh, yLow, yClose] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high[1], low[1], close[1]], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

PP = (yClose + yHigh + yLow) / 3
R1 = (PP * 2) - yLow
R2 = PP + (yHigh - yLow)
R3 = yHigh + (2 * (PP - yLow))
S1 = (PP * 2) - yHigh
S2 = PP - (yHigh - yLow)
S3 = yLow - (2 * (yHigh - PP))

// Plotting PPs
plot(PP, color = color.rgb(152, 155, 163, 50),title = "Pivot Point")
plot(R1, color = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50), title = "Resistance 1")
plot(R2, color = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50), title = "R2")
plot(R3, color = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50), title = "R3")
plot(S1, color = color.rgb(0, 211, 7, 50), title = "Support 1")
plot(S2, color = color.rgb(0, 211, 7, 50), title = "S2")
plot(S3, color = color.rgb(0, 211, 7, 50), title = "S3")

PivotLabel = label.new(bar_index + 2, PP, text = "P", color = color.silver, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.rgb(152, 155, 163, 50))
R1Label = label.new(bar_index + 2, R1, text = "R1", color = color.red, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50))
R2Label = label.new(bar_index + 2, R2, text = "R2", color = color.red, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50))
R3Label = label.new(bar_index + 2, R3, text = "R3", color = color.red, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50))
S1Label = label.new(bar_index + 2, S1, text = "S1", color = color.green, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.rgb(0, 211, 7, 50))
S2Label =label.new(bar_index + 2, S2, text = "S2", color = color.green, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.rgb(0, 211, 7, 50))
S3Label = label.new(bar_index + 2, S3, text = "S3", color = color.green, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.rgb(0, 211, 7, 50))

label.delete(PivotLabel[1])
label.delete(R1Label[1])
label.delete(R2Label[1])
label.delete(R3Label[1])
label.delete(S1Label[1])
label.delete(S2Label[1])
label.delete(S3Label[1])


This is how you call the plotshape() function.
plotshape(bullishEngulfing != na, buyCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, text='Long', textcolor=color.gray, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title = "Long Signal")

However, if you look at its signature, the second argument is title.
plotshape(series, title, style, location, color, offset, text, textcolor, editable, size, show_last, display, format, precision, force_overlay) → void

So, you are passing buyCondition to its title argument and at the end, you have title = "Long Signal". So, you have two title arguments and that's what the compiler is telling you.
You probably don't want to pass buyCondition to the title argument. If you want to use it as a condition, then and it in the series argument like below.
plotshape(bullishEngulfing != na and buyCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, text='Long', textcolor=color.gray, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title = "Long Signal")


everyone should always use name arguments to avoid confusion....
